# Calling EventHandlers for static method

Tags: c#, static

I have one class it has two static methods A() and B().
Here A() methods needs to subscribe some events like:

```
push.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.DeviceSubscriptionExpired(Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired); 
push.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged += new PushSharp.Common.ChannelEvents.DeviceSubscriptionIdChanged(Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged);
```

I kept them in constructor of the class but it is not working for static methods Actually when controls pass to static method it dont pass through constructor.
Here I want two things :

1. How to set eventhandler in class so that it could be saved by static methods?
2. How to subscribe and unsubscribe them so that they can't overlap?

Comment: There must be a known point in time where you want to subscribe, and another when you want to subscribe. You just need to write a static `Subscribe()` method and a static `Unsubscribe()` method to call at the appropriate times... I may be missing something here.

Comment: Pretty unclear, but a very strong hint that these methods should *not* be static.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing what you want to do in the static constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
       // TODO : Attach your static event handlers here
    }
}
```

Please do note that you can only use static properties, fields, events, etc in here. If your object is a singleton, then there are other implications and you should read Jon Skeet's article on singleton implementation in C# to get a full view of things.